# Rendering a radio button in the qtip

Tags: jquery, qtip

I am using the qTip jquery plugin for rendering the tool-tips.

In a tool-tip there was radio button group,I want to click the radio button for functionality.

The tooltip is rendering but I cant able to click over the tooltip,the tooltip is going out on mouse out the element

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the display of the tooltip to [fixed](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/docs/hide/#fixed) mode and add a bit of a hide [delay](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/docs/hide/#delay) as noted in the documentation so that it doesn't hide while the mouse is "in transit" to the tooltip.

You didn't specify which version you're using, but I'll assume qTip2:

```
$('.selector').qtip({
    hide: {
        fixed: true,
        delay: 300
    }
});
```